# Access a .plist file in an iOS app through iTunes (or other ?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I'm coding a small app to manage a guest list. To stock this list, I use a .plist file (It is an array -> .plist is practical.) I wanted to have the possibility of editing this file with my computer (I have to fill it with 1000 people or more...) Have some one a solution to make a file accessible with a Mac (With iTunes I suppose) ? (as Stop Motion : You can take the videos you have made in iTunes).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW30):

> **File-Sharing Support**
>  File-sharing support lets apps make user data files available in iTunes 9.1 and later. An app that declares its
>   support for file sharing makes the contents of its /Documents
>   directory available to the user. The user can then move files in and
>   out of this directory as needed from iTunes. This feature does not
>   allow your app to share files with other apps on the same device; that
>   behavior requires the pasteboard or a document interaction controller
>   object.
>
> To enable file sharing for your app, do the following:
>
> 1. Add the **UIFileSharingEnabled** key to your app’s Info.plist file, and set the value of the key to **YES**. (The actual key name is
>      "Application supports iTunes file sharing")
> 2. Put whatever files you want to share in your app’s Documents directory.
> 3. When the device is plugged into the user’s computer, iTunes displays a File Sharing section in the Apps tab of the selected
>      device.
> 4. The user can add files to this directory or move files to the desktop.
>
> Apps that support file sharing should be able to recognize when files
>   have been added to the Documents directory and respond appropriately.
>   For example, your app might make the contents of any new files
>   available from its interface. You should never present the user with
>   the list of files in this directory and ask them to decide what to do
>   with those files.
>
> For additional information about the UIFileSharingEnabled key, see
>   Information [Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009247).